# I need to update my opengl drivers to play counter strike source ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl

I get an error `glgeterror` when I launch counter strike source. Normal counter strike runs fine, this is all through steam.

I've done some digging and I need to get newer opengl drivers, My laptop has GPU 945gm intel and 1.4 opengl from what I can see.

Here are the sites
[ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206626) and [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/)

I'm stuck at the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Ubuntu 13.10 doesnt have this ?

Also from the graphics driver guide I'm not sure which of these I should be using

To force the use of gallium i915 driver:

```
$ LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/dri-alternates glxgears -info
```

To force the use of gallium llvmpipe software render:

```
$ LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 glxgears -info
```

To force the use of old non-gallium software render:

```
$ LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/dri-alternates glxgears -info
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

to get the latest openGL 3.3 compliant drivers and all the latest updates for them you should install the oibaf ppa.

sudo apt-get install ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

run that from the command line or include the oibaf ppa as a update source in the software sources.